# Debugger says 'layout forced' problem in Firefox

Tags: javascript

While debugging, I see the message "Layout was forced before the page was fully loaded. If stylesheets are not yet loaded this may cause a flash of unstyled content." When I get this message, Firefox does not find my functions in

```html
<script src='Game_Help.js' onload="alert('loaded')"></script>
```

If I remove `<script>`, the message goes away, but of course those functions are still not being found.

The strange thing is, I have a similar problem with Edge. Chrome works fine.

PS: I used the `onload` function to see if script was being loaded.
I can make a workaround using an iframe, but that seems strange.

Comment: What's in the script? Where is it placed in your HTML file? Can you use `defer` or `async` to allow the page to load first?

Comment: Could you share an example of a function that isn't being found? Please share it in its global scope. Also, check for any Javascript errors. And where in your HTML are you including the script? If it's in the `<head>`, try loading the script in the **bottom** of your `<body>`

Comment: Reduced JAVASCRIPT to ```function Show_help (){ alert('here')}``` with no luck. Tried putting external ```<script src='''></script>``` before and after the inline script before the ``</head>``` tag.  Some documentation says that external scripts should be in the 'head' part of the HTML. Since it worked in Chrome, I consider this a browser problem and not a coding problem. I ended up using an ```<iframe>``` to get around the problem. In a way that was a cleaner solution because it doesn't use any additional storage unless it is invoked (by using the (by clicking the HELP button).

Comment: I posted an answer but my explanation was incorrect. Essentially if you move the script to the body, it will not give the warning. I'm looking into whether it can remain in the header and not give the warning.

Comment: My scripts are all located just before the </body> tag, not called on an event, but I am getting the warning "Layout was forced before the page was fully loaded."

Answer (score 5):

So what is happening is that the alert itself is interrupting the loading of content, causing the warning. So to fix it (and keep the script in the head section), remove the onLoad event from your script tag, and add an event listener containing the alert to your external javascript file:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){ alert('loaded') });
```

This listener will wait until other content is loaded before it will run.

The other way to fix this is to move the script tag to the body (HTML loads top to bottom, so you are just letting everything else load up more or less until it gets to the script). If your content is fairly complex or there are multiple scripts using the event listener will be a more robust and specific solution.